# How to apply depth map gradually instead of binary?

Tags: opengl-es

I'm working on a mobile app that renders virtual objects on a real environment (AR), kind of like Pokemon Go. The background of every frame is the camera image, passed to the fragment shader. Along with the camera image, a procedurally computed depth image is passed to the fragment shader as a texture.

I would like to use the depth texture as a depth map for the virtual objects. Currently, this works, but doesn't look good for the following reason. The comparison between the depth of the object and the depth from the depth texture is binary, resulting in visible edges of occlusion on the virtual object. I would like the occlusion to gradually fade in, instead of having a hard edge. How can I achieve that?

The current comparison in the fragment shader looks like this:

```
float visibility = clamp(0.5 * (depth_mm - asset_depth_mm) + 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
gl_FragColor.a = visibility * object_color.a;
```

How to change this so that the regions where the object becomes occluded look gradually fading, instead of an instant change in alpha?

Answer (score 0):

I would change:

```
float visibility = clamp(0.5 * (depth_mm - asset_depth_mm) + 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
```

to

```
float visibility = clamp(0.001 * (depth_mm - asset_depth_mm) + 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
```

(tweaking the valid of that 0.001 multiplier to whatever looks good)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Your suggestion assumes smoothness of the background depth. If there is a jump in the values of depth texture (like between a close table and a far wall) in close pixels, this change doesn't look better than the original solution.